# Word VB How to add a word to a user custom dictionary

Tags: vba, ms-word

The dictionary object does not contain a method to do this. Do I just write into the dictionary file itself? If so, I presume I can just append to the end and do not need to preserve the alphabetical order. How do I refresh Word so that the new word is no longer underscored with red showing a spelling error?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to make sure the dictionary is not loaded in Word. Use the `CustomDictionaries ([filename]).Delete` method. (This removes it from memory and does not delete the file.)

The open the file (it's plain text) and add the terms at the end - there's no need to sort them.

Use `CustomDictionaries.Add( [filename])` to re-load it.

It may be necessary to force a spell-check to get Word to remove the "spelling error" markings already present in the document. Having Word continually checking spelling in the document would slow things down - it needs to be re-triggered.

Comment: Ok, somethings very strange happens when I triy this. After adding a word to the dictionary as described above, and then typing a space in the document (which triggers a recheck) some words that are in the custom dictionary that were not showing red lines suddenly have red lines. Going into proofing and unchecking the custom dictionary, and then going into proofing and ticking the dictionary again, makes all the red lines disappear, Initially nearly all words became red lined. I sorted the custom dictionary and then added an alphabetically last word and only it and one other were red lined.

Comment: Even more strange, if after running the macro I go to options/proofing and click recheck document, every word that is in the custom dictionary is red lined. If I then press F7 for a spell check, as each one is selected in the dialog, pressing cancel removes the red line. F7 again followed by cancel removes the red line from the next, and so on. The unchecking, re checking described above also removes all these red lines.